# Plotly Strip plot - color by continuous scale

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, plotly-python

I would like to use `plotly.express.strip` to show the distribution of my data points. The catch is that I would also like to color each data point according to its value.
As an example, taken from Plotly's documentation:

```py
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.strip(df, x="total_bill", y="day")
fig.show()
```

This shows:
[image: Plotly strip example]
But I would like the points to be colored by the "total_bill" amount using a continuous color scale.

From my research I haven't found a way to do this using this specific plot (i.e. I can't use a px.scatter).

Is there any way to do this? Thanks

Comment: It would be easier if we could use scatter plots, but what are the reasons why we can't? `fig = px.scatter(df, y='day', x='total_bill',color='total_bill');fig.update_traces(marker_size=9);fig.show()`

Comment: The reason is that I want to have some jitter, to be able to visualize my data even if some points overlap. As far as I've seen, px.strip is the only way Plotly can show this kind of plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a jitter. I applied a pseudo-jitter function to the y-axis to create a scatter plot. The jitter function was inspired by [the contents of this page](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/blob/03979d105c65dda3df3a155322eaff18f203b03f/doc/unconverted/python/cars-exploration.md). It may differ from the original graphing logic. At first, I wrote the graph by extracting the days of the week in a loop process, but since the color scale duplicates, I described all the days of the week and added the color scale only for Saturday since Saturday contains the largest value.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np

df = px.data.tips()
N = len(df)

fig = go.Figure()

dfs = df.query('day == "Sun"')
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=dfs['total_bill'], 
    y=0 + np.random.rand(N) * 0.2,
    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(
        size=9,
        color=dfs['total_bill'],
    ),
    name='Sun',
))

dfst = df.query('day == "Sat"')
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=dfst['total_bill'], 
    y=1 + np.random.rand(N) * 0.2,
    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(
        size=9,
        color=dfst['total_bill'],
        colorbar=dict(
            title='total_bill',
        ),
        colorscale='Plasma'
    ),
    name='Sat',
))

dfth = df.query('day == "Thur"')
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=dfth['total_bill'], 
    y=2 + np.random.rand(N) * 0.2,
    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(
        size=9,
        color=dfth['total_bill'],
    ),
    name='Thur',
))

dff = df.query('day == "Fri"')
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=dff['total_bill'], 
    y=3 + np.random.rand(N) * 0.2,
    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(
        size=9,
        color=dff['total_bill'],
    ),
    name='Fri',
))

fig.update_layout(showlegend=False, coloraxis_showscale=True)
fig.update_yaxes(tickvals=[0,1,2,3], ticktext=['Sun','Sat','Thur','Fri'])
fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use Plotly or Seaborn

**Plotly**

I am using grays here (white to black), but you can choose what makes sense. Check the RGB values... `n_colors` will break up the colors into groups. Used 4 as there are 4 unique days here

Code:

```
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.colors import n_colors

df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.strip(df, x="total_bill", y="day", color="day", color_discrete_sequence = n_colors('rgb(0, 0, 0)', 'rgb(255, 255, 255)', 4, colortype = 'rgb'))
```

**Output**

[image]

**Seaborn**

It is actually easier in seaborn as you can use `palette` and using `jitter=True`, you should be good to go

Code:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.stripplot(data = df, x='total_bill', y = 'day', palette = 'gray', jitter=True)
```

**Output**

[image]

**Option 3 - continuous X-axis**
If you need the gradient on the X-axis, you need add `hue='total_bill'` to the sns plot. Code below... I have removed the legend as it will show all colors, which you probably don't need

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.stripplot(data = df, x='total_bill', y = 'day', hue = 'total_bill', palette = 'gray', jitter=True)
plt.legend([],[], frameon=False)
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Here you are coloring by "day", not by "total_bill". It's a good idea, however, to also look at seaborn's functions, thank you

Comment: @itscarlayall - My bad. You need to add `hue='total_bill'` for seaborn plot. Response updated with the new plot. For px, think you will need to do the colors based on number of colors, etc. before using `n_colors()`. So, not as easy....